# CMap with a CRuntimeClass as the key

Tags: c++, stl, mfc, msdn

I want to map my objects by their runtime classes...or some unique ID that associates them with their runtime class. I won't hardcode data(EG: CObject = 2, CObjectEx = 3)

CRuntimeClass has the m_lpszClassName and m_wSchema(m_wSchema is only used for Implement_Dynamic classes, and I have a lot of serial classes where schema is 0, so that won't work). maybe the CRunTimeClass* that GetRuntimeClass() returns could be a unique key?

Do all CObject's of type CMyInheritedObject return the exact same pointer to a CRuntmeClass object? hence i could use CRuntimeClass* as a unique key for all classes of the same type?

Comment: I can use the CRuntimeClass* that is returned by CObject::GetRuntimeClass() as a key to map objects by their class.

Comment: Actually, [CRuntimeClass::m_wSchema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9h5x2k4.aspx) is only used for classes implemented using [IMPLEMENT_SERIAL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a94da1y0.aspx). It designates the version of the serialized format, when streamed out to a `CArchive`, or read back in. IMPLEMENT_SERIAL requires [IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fsfk9dy.aspx), to allow streaming objects out of a `CArchive`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the CRuntimeClass is always unique for all objects of a given type. Otherwise IsKindOf and the MFC macros DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST wouldn't work.

If CMyInheritedObject uses the IMPLEMENT_ macros the appropriate static objects are created.